# Python - How to compare the values for row and previous row and return time difference based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset that contians TimeStamp, CustomerID and Session ID.
As you can see the clientId and Session_ID do repeat over the time.

```
Timestamp   clientId    Session_ID
0   6/12/2021 15:05 27255667    ab89
1   6/12/2021 19:56 118698247   684a
2   6/12/2021 23:59 99492237    a4fd
3   6/12/2021 23:59 99492237    a4fd
4   6/12/2021 23:59 99492237    a4fd
5   6/12/2021 23:59 99492237    a4fd
6   6/13/2021 0:06  99492237    a5fd
7   6/13/2021 0:41  142584462   c23000
8   6/13/2021 23:33 142584462   c23000
9   6/13/2021 23:33 142584462   c23000
10  6/13/2021 23:33 142584462   c23000
11  6/13/2021 23:34 142584462   c23000
12  6/13/2021 23:34 142584462   c23000
13  6/13/2021 23:34 142584462   7d97
```

I need to find the instnaces where clientId gets new SessionID and then i need to calculate the time differnce between previous Session_ID and the new Session_Id for the same client.

For example client_ID:99492237 had 3 same Session and then 4th one was different. The time difference would be 6/13/2021 0:06 - 6/12/2021 23:59

This is what I tried so far:

```
# importing dependencies
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# importing data from SampleData.csv
df = pd.read_csv('data/SampleData.csv' ,converters={'clientId':str})
#converting timestamp string into timestap datatype
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])
df.sort_values(["Timestamp", "clientId"], ascending = (True, True))
df["SameSession?"] = np.where((df['clientId'] == df['clientId'].shift(-1)) & (df['Session_ID'] == df['Session_ID'].shift(-1)), "YES", "NO")
minMax = df.groupby('clientId').agg(minTime=('Time', 'min'), maxTime=('Time', 'max'))
minMax['Diff'] = minMax['maxTime'] - minMax['minTime']
df = df.merge(minMax[['Diff']], on='clientId')
```

So I tried sorting everything by Time and ClientID so I can get same ClientId one after another. Than i tried comparing the row to row above for ClientID and Session. IF both are same, return Yes,if one is different than show NO. And then i did calculation between First and Last instace of ClientID. But i am getting wrong values when i compare rows to row above.

Here is the output

```
        Timestamp   clientId    Session_ID  Time    SameSession?    Diff
0   6/12/2021 15:05 27255667    ab89    2021-06-12 15:05:00 NO  0 days 00:00:00
1   6/12/2021 19:56 118698247   684a    2021-06-12 19:56:00 NO  0 days 00:00:00
2   6/12/2021 23:59 99492237    a4fd    2021-06-12 23:59:00 YES 0 days 00:07:00
3   6/12/2021 23:59 99492237    a4fd    2021-06-12 23:59:00 YES 0 days 00:07:00
4   6/12/2021 23:59 99492237    a4fd    2021-06-12 23:59:00 YES 0 days 00:07:00
5   6/12/2021 23:59 99492237    a4fd    2021-06-12 23:59:00 NO  0 days 00:07:00
6   6/13/2021 0:06  99492237    a5fd    2021-06-13 00:06:00 NO  0 days 00:07:00
7   6/13/2021 0:41  142584462   c23000  2021-06-13 00:41:00 YES 0 days 22:53:00
8   6/13/2021 23:33 142584462   c23000  2021-06-13 23:33:00 YES 0 days 22:53:00
9   6/13/2021 23:33 142584462   c23000  2021-06-13 23:33:00 YES 0 days 22:53:00
10  6/13/2021 23:33 142584462   c23000  2021-06-13 23:33:00 YES 0 days 22:53:00
11  6/13/2021 23:34 142584462   c23000  2021-06-13 23:34:00 YES 0 days 22:53:00
12  6/13/2021 23:34 142584462   c23000  2021-06-13 23:34:00 NO  0 days 22:53:00
13  6/13/2021 23:34 142584462   7d97    2021-06-13 23:34:00 NO  0 days 22:53:00
```

SO how do I need to adjust my code so i can show the new Session_ID for the same ClientId and show the time difference between new Session and previous session for the same client?

The output i expect to get should look like this:

```
            Timestamp   clientId    Session_ID  Time    SameSession?    Diff
0   6/12/2021 15:05 27255667    ab89    2021-06-12 15:05:00 NO  0 days 
1   6/12/2021 19:56 118698247   684a    2021-06-12 19:56:00 NO  0 days 
2   6/12/2021 23:59 99492237    a4fd    2021-06-12 23:59:00 YES 0 days 
3   6/12/2021 23:59 99492237    a4fd    2021-06-12 23:59:00 YES 0 days 
4   6/12/2021 23:59 99492237    a4fd    2021-06-12 23:59:00 YES 0 days 
5   6/12/2021 23:59 99492237    a4fd    2021-06-12 23:59:00 YES 0 days 
6   6/13/2021 0:06  99492237    a5fd    2021-06-13 00:06:00 NO  0 days 00:07:00
7   6/13/2021 0:41  142584462   c23000  2021-06-13 00:41:00 NO  0 days 
8   6/13/2021 23:33 142584462   c23000  2021-06-13 23:33:00 YES 0 days 
9   6/13/2021 23:33 142584462   c23000  2021-06-13 23:33:00 YES 0 days 
10  6/13/2021 23:33 142584462   c23000  2021-06-13 23:33:00 YES 0 days 
11  6/13/2021 23:34 142584462   c23000  2021-06-13 23:34:00 YES 0 days 
12  6/13/2021 23:34 142584462   c23000  2021-06-13 23:34:00 YES 0 days 
13  6/13/2021 23:34 142584462   7d97    2021-06-13 23:34:00 NO  0 days 22:53:00
```

Comment: what results did you expect? Add `output` with expected values.

Comment: as for me you have wrong values in `SameSession?`. I would expect results which you can get when you use `shift(1)` instead of `shift(-1)`

Comment: @furas - I added the expected output. And i just tried using shift(1) and it seems to do SameSession? column correctly which is weird. I thought -1 would be to compare to row above...

Comment: So how do i show time differences only at the row where i compare the first new session against last session of the same client?

Comment: I'm not sure but it may need few steps. It seems last row in every `clientId` and it would have to skip it when result is zero `00:00:00`

Comment: When I export this in excel, the column diff is in some weird format like 1.06597222222222. How to format it so i can export it as it is on that example?

Comment: this column has type `Timedelta` and you would have to convert to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get correct values in SameSession you need `shift(1)` instead of `shift(-1)`

---

Your `Diff` has type `Timedelta` and you would need to convert it to string to get it in `excel`.

---

I would create column with default value `0 days`

```
 df['Diff'] = '0 days'
```

and later work with every group to put new value only in last row in group

```
groups = df.groupby('clientId')

for val, group in groups:
    diff = group['Time'].max() - group['Time'].min()

    last_index = group.index[-1]

    if diff.total_seconds() > 0:
         df.loc[last_row,'Diff'] = str(diff)
    #else:        
    #    df.loc[last_row,'Diff'] = '0 days'
```

---

Minimal working code

```
text = '''Timestamp,clientId,Session_ID
6/12/2021 15:05,27255667,ab89
6/12/2021 19:56,118698247,684a
6/12/2021 23:59,99492237,a4fd
6/12/2021 23:59,99492237,a4fd
6/12/2021 23:59,99492237,a4fd
6/12/2021 23:59,99492237,a4fd
6/13/2021 00:06,99492237,a5fd
6/13/2021 00:41,142584462,c23000
6/13/2021 23:33,142584462,c23000
6/13/2021 23:33,142584462,c23000
6/13/2021 23:33,142584462,c23000
6/13/2021 23:34,142584462,c23000
6/13/2021 23:34,142584462,c23000
6/13/2021 23:34,142584462,7d97'''

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

# importing data from SampleData.csv
#df = pd.read_csv('data/SampleData.csv', converters={'clientId':str})
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), converters={'clientId':str})
#print(df)

df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])
df.sort_values(["Timestamp", "clientId"], ascending = (True, True))
df["SameSession?"] = np.where((df['clientId'] == df['clientId'].shift(1)) & (df['Session_ID'] == df['Session_ID'].shift(1)), "YES", "NO")

# create column with default value
df['Diff'] = '0 days'
#print(df)

groups = df.groupby('clientId')

for val, group in groups:
    diff = group['Time'].max() - group['Time'].min()

    last_index = group.index[-1]
    
    if diff.total_seconds() > 0:
         df.loc[last_index,'Diff'] = str(diff)
    #else:        
    #    df.loc[last_index,'Diff'] = '0 days'
        
print(df[['clientId', 'Diff']])
```

Result:

```
     clientId             Diff
0    27255667           0 days
1   118698247           0 days
2    99492237           0 days
3    99492237           0 days
4    99492237           0 days
5    99492237           0 days
6    99492237  0 days 00:07:00
7   142584462           0 days
8   142584462           0 days
9   142584462           0 days
10  142584462           0 days
11  142584462           0 days
12  142584462           0 days
13  142584462  0 days 22:53:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the dataframe by values in `clientId`, `Session_ID`, and `Timestamp`, then groupby `clientId`, and `Session_ID`, then finally call `diff` for the `Timestamp` column, and assign it back to the `Diff` column.

```py
df['Diff'] = df.sort_values(['clientId','Session_ID', 'Timestamp']).groupby(['clientId','Session_ID'])['Timestamp'].diff()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
             Timestamp   clientId Session_ID            Diff
0  2021-06-12 15:05:00   27255667       ab89             NaT
1  2021-06-12 19:56:00  118698247       684a             NaT
2  2021-06-12 23:59:00   99492237       a4fd             NaT
3  2021-06-12 23:59:00   99492237       a4fd 0 days 00:00:00
4  2021-06-12 23:59:00   99492237       a4fd 0 days 00:00:00
5  2021-06-12 23:59:00   99492237       a4fd 0 days 00:00:00
6  2021-06-13 00:06:00   99492237       a5fd             NaT
7  2021-06-13 00:41:00  142584462     c23000             NaT
8  2021-06-13 23:33:00  142584462     c23000 0 days 22:52:00
9  2021-06-13 23:33:00  142584462     c23000 0 days 00:00:00
10 2021-06-13 23:33:00  142584462     c23000 0 days 00:00:00
11 2021-06-13 23:34:00  142584462     c23000 0 days 00:01:00
12 2021-06-13 23:34:00  142584462     c23000 0 days 00:00:00
13 2021-06-13 23:34:00  142584462       7d97             NaT
```

If needed, `fillna` the `NaT` values by `pd.to_timedelta(0, 'S')`

Comment: I think OP expects different value in row `6`. You have `NaT` but OP expect `7 minutes` - time difference between sesssion `a4fd` and `a5fd`